# Recorded a macro in excel and I want to change something in the code

Tags: vba, excel

I've recorded a macro in excel.
I input data in a column. Afterwards I want that data to appear somewhere else.
I want to repeat this action a few times, I only want the data to always appear a row to the right. I know there is suppose to be a very simple solution to this, but I'm very new to this. 
If my info isn't very clear please ask for more details.
This is the code I have so far:

```
Sub adding_another_trip()
'
' adding_another_trip Macro
' Use this macro to move this trip to the overview and add another trip
'

'
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-6
Range("C2:C11").Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=18
Range("C26").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-9
Range("H13").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=9
Range("C36").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-6
Range("I13").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=6
Range("C37").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False


End Sub
```

This is a capture of the sheet. So the info from above has to appear in the overview, and afterwards if someone fills out the table above again it has to appear in trip 2. I hope this clears things up.
[image: link capture sheet]

Comment: It would be helpful to see a copy of your spreadsheet. From this detail, I cannot figure out why you are copying C2:C11 and pasting in C26 , then copying H13 and pasting in C36, then copying I13 and pasting in C37... Basically seeing the table itself might help in understanding what you are trying to accompilsh. As a starter you don't need lines that say "ActiveWindow.SmallScroll" - those lines are just saying that you scrolled through your sheet and have no bearing on your copy and paste code

Comment: Going on your statement of _I only want the data to always appear a row to the right._ you could use:  `Sub adding_another_trip(): Selection.Offset(, 1).Value = Selection.Value: End Sub`

Comment: I believe you meant column.

Comment: How many trips do you want to be able to handle?

Comment: @Wookies-Will-Code you're right I do mean columns.
and I would like to be able to handle 3 trips.

Comment: @Analyst123456789 I have removed the "ActiveWindow.SmallScroll" it was because it was a recording of a marco and in that recording I scrolled a few times. But you're right I do not need it. 
I have also added a screenshot of the worksheet, I hope it becomes a bit clearer that way.

Comment: Did you get this squared away?  You could use copy and paste but either way you are going to have to specify a column locator in your code.  Rather than do that I built an array to hold your copy data, and then assigned the array to the paste rows.  Copy cells -> Array -> Paste cells, when your "entry forms" get bigger it is easier to do this, you can load an array from many places "user form" controls, cell based worksheet "entry forms", file data, etc. etc

Answer (score 0):

This might help you learn some VBA and start you on the path . . .

There are many way to achieve what you are doing, one wrinkle is that you copy is not a contiguous range, it could be two copies with the second range transposed on the paste (column to rows, or rows to columns).
As you are making a data entry form, these can get large and require validation ranges . . . this one seems straight forward though.

I did not format for currency (Euro) and ran out of time on a few things.
Just wanted to show you some powerful tools in a simple setting that makes those tools look too complicated, but it is the start of learning what is really possible (I am still learning).

If you study this code and look on the forum (and internet) you will be off and running to be the Excel guru of your tribe.

```
Option Explicit

'You can make the Sub below Public if you want to run as a Macro
'Since it is a button and does not need any added scope, Private is fine
'Find the button Sub in your sheet, there is clearly a button on it
'Might want to add other buttons to clear the trip copy range and the trip sumamry/overview ranges

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'Having a worksheet variable means less typing later
Dim ws As Worksheet

'This will be our looping variable to find the next open column
Dim i As Integer
'This will be out looping variable to fill in the rows
Dim j As Integer

'Define an Array to hold your copy values
Dim arrCopy(0 To 11) As Long

'Rather than hard code we will make variables for the rows to copy
'They won't cahnge unless you change your form
Dim rCopy1 As Double
Dim rCopy2 As Double
Dim rCopy3 As Double
Dim rCopy4 As Double
Dim rCopy5 As Double
Dim rCopy6 As Double
Dim rCopy7 As Double
Dim rCopy8 As Double
Dim rCopy9 As Double
Dim rCopy10 As Double

'Dim the sum rows we need at the end
Dim rNights As Double
Dim rCost As Double
Dim rTime As Double

'Rather than hard code we will make variables for the cols to copy
'They won't change unless you change your form
Dim cCopy1 As Double
Dim cCopy2 As Double
Dim cCopy3 As Double

'Declare some paste Variables
Dim rFirstPaste As Double
Dim cFirstPaste As Double
Dim cLastPaste As Double


'Intialiaze the variables, this is where changes would be made if you change the form
'Change the "Sheet1" to your sheet name, or name the sheets in Properties and skip this step forever
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
rCopy1 = ws.Range("B3").Row 'The B is not what matters in these lines, its not a row
rCopy2 = ws.Range("B4").Row
rCopy3 = ws.Range("B5").Row
rCopy4 = ws.Range("B6").Row
rCopy5 = ws.Range("B7").Row
rCopy6 = ws.Range("B8").Row
rCopy7 = ws.Range("B9").Row
rCopy8 = ws.Range("B10").Row
rCopy9 = ws.Range("B11").Row
rCopy10 = ws.Range("B13").Row 'BTW - Two items in this row

rFirstPaste = ws.Range("C26").Row 'The C is not what matters in these lines, its not a row

rNights = ws.Range("C35").Row 'we will need these for the summary at the end
rCost = ws.Range("D36").Row
rTime = ws.Range("D37").Row

cCopy1 = ws.Range("B3").Column 'The # is not what matters in this line, its not a Column
cCopy2 = ws.Range("C13").Column
cCopy3 = ws.Range("D13").Column

cFirstPaste = ws.Range("C26").Column
cLastPaste = ws.Range("E26").Column

'Load the array the hard way
arrCopy(0) = ws.Cells(rCopy1, cCopy1).Value 'Flight, = ws.Cells(3,2) which is ws.Range("B3") in (row,col)
arrCopy(1) = ws.Cells(rCopy2, cCopy1).Value 'Train
arrCopy(2) = ws.Cells(rCopy3, cCopy1).Value 'Hotel
arrCopy(3) = ws.Cells(rCopy4, cCopy1).Value 'Rental Car
arrCopy(4) = ws.Cells(rCopy5, cCopy1).Value 'Taxi/metro
arrCopy(5) = ws.Cells(rCopy6, cCopy1).Value 'Per Diem
arrCopy(6) = ws.Cells(rCopy7, cCopy1).Value 'Internet
arrCopy(7) = 0 'We are going to skip this element in the loop
arrCopy(8) = ws.Cells(rCopy8, cCopy1).Value '# of Trips
arrCopy(9) = ws.Cells(rCopy9, cCopy1).Value '# of night per trip
arrCopy(10) = ws.Cells(rCopy10, cCopy2).Value '#Travel Cost per trip
arrCopy(11) = ws.Cells(rCopy10, cCopy3).Value '#Travel Time per trip

'Find the first open Column in the Overview Range
For i = cFirstPaste To cLastPaste + 1 'We traverse column 3 to 6, that is one past the boundary for error check

    If ws.Cells(rFirstPaste, i) = "" And i <= cLastPaste Then 'Is C26, D26, E26 empty? did we go too far F26

        'The Column stopped at the empty column and it is in our range, so fill it in
        For j = 0 To 11 'You have 12 paste rows, you skip #8 whic is 7 for us in zero based offset
            If j <> 7 Then 'If j does not equal 7, we are skipping this number
                ws.Cells(rFirstPaste + j, i) = arrCopy(j)
            Else ' Do Nothing
            End If
        Next j 'Add 1 to j

        'We have filled the paste range, this will break the loop
        i = 9999 'We are not searching 100,000 columns it is very out of bounds

        'Update the summary, shouldn't hard code these, there is a temptation on smaller forms
        ws.Range("C21") = WorksheetFunction.Sum(ws.Range("C35:E35"))
        ws.Range("D21") = WorksheetFunction.Sum(ws.Range("C36:E36"))
        ws.Range("E21") = WorksheetFunction.Sum(ws.Range("C37:E37"))
    Else
    End If
Next i 'Add 1 to i

'Test i to see if it is out of bounds, exception is our break loop (9999) + 1
If i > cLastPaste And i <> 10000 Then
    MsgBox "There is a 3 trip limit", vbExclamation, "ERROR: Trip Limit"
Else ' Do Nothing
End If


End Sub
```

Happy Coding!

[image]